# End game if entire team is dead [Roblox Lua]

Tags: lua, roblox

I am working on a game where a player is randomly selected to be the beast and has to kill the entire investigator team.

But I am having issues with the game recognizing that the entire investigator team is dead.

I've inserted my code below;

```
function playerAlive()
local activePlayers = game.Workspace.ImportantBlock:GetAttribute("numPlayers")
local inGame = game.Workspace.ImportantBlock:GetAttribute("inGame")
local playerTeam = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Team:GetAttribute()
if playerTeam(Investigator)==0 then
    game.Workspace.ImportantBlock:SetAttribute("inGame", false)
end
wait(1)
playerAlive()
end
```

(I connected important values to costume attributes within a block I named "ImportantBlock" because I am having issues with global variables, so far it caused no problems.)

Comment: There are a lot of odd things in the code above, like you are calling `playerTeam(Investigator)` which is the returned value from `game.Players.LocalPlayer.Team:GetAttribute()` and you did not define `Investigator` in the above code so not sure if you meant to make it a string maybe

Comment: Ah, the values have been defined outside the function, but still inside the script. I do not get any nil/not defined error, just nothing happens.

Comment: `Team:GetAttribute()` is wrong, you either don't need to call GetAttribute, or you need to give it an attribute name to get. Also, it seems like you're checking how many players are in the team, that's not how it works. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two lines which are problematic:

```
local playerTeam = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Team:GetAttribute()
if playerTeam(Investigator)==0 then
```

What you seem to want to do is to check how many players are in the "Investigator" team. However, you're trying to call the playerTeam variable (as a function) with an argument, called Investigator, and comparing that.

`playerTeam` will never be a function (attributes can't be functions). Besides, a `GetAttribute` call without arguments will error.

The way to count the players in a team is the following:

```lua
 -- this should probably be at the top of your file, but it works anywhere
local Teams = game:GetService("Teams")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local InvestigatorTeam = Teams["Investigator"]

-- in your function:
local count = 0
for _, player in ipairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if player.Team == InvestigatorTeam then
        count += 1
    end
end

if count == 0 then
    --no players left
end
```

P.S. You're setting yourself up with a nice stack overflow error here. You keep calling the `playerAlive` function in itself until there are no players. If you keep doing this long enough, the stack will get filled up and your script will crash.

Your can avoid this like so:

```lua
function countPlayers()
    local count = 0
    for _, player in ipairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
        if player.Team == InvestigatorTeam then
            count += 1
        end
    end
    return count
end

function checkGameEnded()
    while true do
        if countPlayers() == 0 then
            game.Workspace.ImportantBlock:SetAttribute("inGame", false)
        end
        
        task.wait(1)
    end
end
```

One final note: don't use `wait()`, use `task.wait()`. The former is old, poorly implemented, inconsistent and most importantly, deprecated. The newer version uses heartbeats to count time.

One more final note: use `workspace` instead of `game.Workspace`.